# How do I filter out all the undesired names in my array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter, unicode-escapes

I want to exclude out some category names but the if checks in switch and in a traditional if statement aren't working. I also want to translate anything Arabic with English which doesn't seem to be applying- any help would be appreciated!

Switch statement:

```
// function customBuildFunction(cats,qty) {
//     var valid_cats = [];
//     for (var i=0; i < cats.length; i++) {
//         switch(true) {
//             case (cats[i].name != 'NA'):  
//             case (cats[i].name != 'New In'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Sale'):  
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Card Holders'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Bags & Accessories'):      
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Heels'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Sneakers'):        
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Flats'):   
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Sandals'): 
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Boots'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Pumps'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Shoes'):       
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Bags'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Loafers & Slippers'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Mules'):   
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Men'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Women'):
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Kids'): 
//             case (cats[i].name != 'Baby'):                    
//                 valid_cats.push(cats[i].name)
//                 break;
          
//         }
//     }
//      // console.log('valid cats', valid_cats)
//      var uniqueBrands = [...new Set(valid_cats)]
//      var uniqueValidCats = uniqueBrands.filter(e => e)

//     console.log('unique', uniqueValidCats);
//     var innerHTML = ''
//     // console.log(qty);
//     for (var j=0; j<qty; j++) {
//          innerHTML += '<div class="container"> ' + '<div class="brands">' + uniqueValidCats[j] + '</div>' + '</div>'
// }
//     return innerHTML
// }
```

Traditional for loop where I attempted to store translates Arabic strings:

```
function customBuildFunction(cats,qty,template,title) {
    var valid_cats = [];
    var str = [];
    var regex = /^[\p{Arabic}\s\p{N}]+$/gm
    console.log('cats', cats)
    for (var i=0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        if (cats[i].name != 'NA' || cats[i].name != 'New In' || cats[i].name != 'Sale' || cats[i].name != 'Card Holders' || cats[i].name != 'Bags & Accessories' || cats[i].name != 'Heels' || cats[i].name != 'Sneakers' || cats[i].name != 'Flats' || cats[i].name != 'Sandals' || cats[i].name != 'Boots' || cats[i].name != 'Pumps' || cats[i].name != 'Shoes' || cats[i].name != 'Bags' || cats[i].name != 'Loafers & Slippers' || cats[i].name != 'Mules' || cats[i].name != 'Men' || cats[i].name != 'Women' || cats[i].name != 'Kids' || cats[i].name != 'Baby') {
            str.push(cats[i].name.replace(regex))
            valid_cats.push(cats[i].name)
        }
    }
        var uniqueBrands = [...new Set(valid_cats)]
        var uniqueValidCats = uniqueBrands.filter(e => e)

    // console.log('unique', uniqueValidCats);
    console.log('str', str);

    var innerHTML = ''
    // console.log(qty);
    for (var j=0; j<qty; j++) {
        innerHTML += '<div class="container"> ' + '<div class="brands">' + uniqueValidCats[j] + '</div>' + '</div>'
}
    return innerHTML
}
```

This is the response from cats that i'm iterating through:

```
cats 
(25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sandals'}
1: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Shoes'}
2: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Mules'}
3: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'BALENCIAGA'}
4: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جديدنا'}
5: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Boots'}
6: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'JIMMY CHOO'}
7: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Men'}
8: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'New In'}
9: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Pumps'}
10: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'ADIDAS'}
11: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جيمي تشو'}
12: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sneakers'}
13: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags & Accessories'}
14: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Baby'}
15: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NA'}
16: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Women'}
17: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NIKE'}
18: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Kids'}
19: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Flats'}
20: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Heels'}
21: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Loafers & Slippers'}
22: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'CHANEL'}
23: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Card Holders'}
24: {rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags'}
length: 25
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: Even though unicode escape is supported in JS, the language specific letter escaping like `\p{Arabic}` is not. But if it is about filtering all items with their `name` only featuring non latin word characters sequences then the OP can filter the last shown array data just by e.g. ... `sampleData.filter(({ name }) => (/^\W+$/).test(name))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"Even though unicode escape is supported in JS, the language specific letter escaping like `\p{Arabic}` is not. But if it is about filtering all items with their `name` only featuring non latin word characters sequences then the OP can filter the last shown array data just by e.g. ... `sampleData.filter(({ name }) => (/^\W+$/).test(name))`."*

```js
const sampleData = [
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sandals'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Shoes'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Mules'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'BALENCIAGA'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جديدنا'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Boots' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'JIMMY CHOO' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Men' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'New In' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Pumps' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'ADIDAS' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جيمي تشو' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sneakers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags & Accessories' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Baby' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NA' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Women' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NIKE' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Kids' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Flats' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Heels' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Loafers & Slippers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'CHANEL' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Card Holders' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags' },
];

console.log(
  sampleData.filter(({ name }) => (/^\W+$/).test(name))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

If one in addition also wants to match (language independent) all names which consists of uppercase letters and whitespace only then one changes the filter slightly to ...

```js
const sampleData = [
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sandals'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Shoes'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Mules'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'BALENCIAGA'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جديدنا'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Boots' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'JIMMY CHOO' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Men' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'New In' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Pumps' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'ADIDAS' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جيمي تشو' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sneakers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags & Accessories' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Baby' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NA' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Women' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NIKE' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Kids' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Flats' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Heels' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Loafers & Slippers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'CHANEL' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Card Holders' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags' },
];

console.log(
  sampleData.filter(({ name }) =>
    (/^\W+$/).test(name) ||
    (/^[\p{Lu}\p{Z}]+$/u).test(name)
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Any other filter condition can be covered by a ***blacklist*** based approach (where one checks the current values against a list of not allowed values) which one combines with the former uppercase testing ...

```js
const sampleData = [
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sandals'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Shoes'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Mules'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'BALENCIAGA'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جديدنا'},
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Boots' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'JIMMY CHOO' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Men' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'New In' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Pumps' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'ADIDAS' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'جيمي تشو' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Sneakers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags & Accessories' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Baby' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NA' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Women' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'NIKE' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Kids' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Flats' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Heels' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Loafers & Slippers' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'CHANEL' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Card Holders' },
  { rectype: 'CAT', name: 'Bags' },
];

console.log(
  sampleData.filter(({ name }) =>
    (/^\W+$/).test(name)
    || (
      (/^[\p{Lu}\p{Z}]+$/u).test(name)
      && !['NA'].includes(name)
    )
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter this was most helpful, indeed!